# Is this user trolling?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, trolling

[Is "head hunter's frequently asked questions list" good idea?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/67696/is-head-hunters-frequently-asked-questions-list-good-idea/67709?noredirect=1#comment187735_67709)

I'm pretty well convinced that this new user is trolling.  The question was ok to begin with but has devolved significantly between the edit and the comments.

Do others see this as a legit question?  If not what is SOP for troll-ish questions?

Comment: Your link goes to a specific comment on an answer. I assume you're referring to the OP of the question?

Comment: I think it's a real question from someone who doesn't really want the answers.

Comment: It looks like someone with extremely rigid thinking who is unable to accept advice.  I have Asperger's syndrome and I'm less rigid than this guy.  PHEW!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about trolling, but the question is very specific to the poster which makes it a bad fit.  I think there could be a question about the idea of presenting the recruiter with an FAQ (and why it's probably a bad idea), but the detail will drive others away from identifying with this person.

Interestingly it's also rhetorical, "why don't recruiters respond when I attach my FAQ?" - they don't respond BECAUSE you attach your FAQ.

Comment: I don't think it's a bad fit, per-se.  I **do** think it's a good example of a bad example of job hunting.  There's good advice in there.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see trolling, in that I don't believe the poster is posting here just to get a rise out of us.

I do see a person who thinks their way is better than everybody else's, and isn't prepared to listen to advice. That's not particularly uncommon, and isn't a good way to get a job. As the post is more a rant than an honest attempt to get information, I'd be tempted to close as "real questions have answers". If nothing else, we should probably *all* so the ongoing debate in comments.

Answer (score 3):

I read the question and see it as a covered way of ranting. Not ranting against specific subjects but against how weird is the world who doesn't understand him.

IMHO he doesn't sound as a troll. Just geninely ridiculous.